# Windows Phone 8.1 Background Task - Can't Debug and won't fire

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

Im having a issue with the Background Tasks in WP8.1
I have created a background task as a windows runtime component following this tutorial : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx

The problem is, i can't get my background task to run. It runs onNetworkChange. When i can to flight mode and back it is not firing. When i go to lifecycle events in the Debug Location toolbar it says No Background tasks. I have debugged the code that registers the background task and it is getting registered. I am also getting 'This breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document' which i think is causing the problem.

I have tried
- deleting the bin and obj folder and rebuilding.
- cleaning the project.
- trying to build the project from scratch.
- turning Just my code option off.
- tried doing the same thing on another machine, still nothing.

My code for registering

```
var taskRegistered = false;
        var exampleTaskName = "UploadTask";

        foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        {
            if (task.Value.Name == exampleTaskName)
            {
                taskRegistered = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!taskRegistered)
        {
            var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

            builder.Name = exampleTaskName;
            builder.TaskEntryPoint = "Tasks.Upload";
            builder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.NetworkStateChange, false));
            BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
        }
```

package manifest file is as follows

```
<Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="Tasks.Upload">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="systemEvent" />
        <m2:Task Type="deviceUse" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

My task looks like this :

```
namespace Tasks
{
public sealed class Upload : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Am i even getting here?");
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help as i've spent far too long getting this to work. Thanks

Comment: Have you added your Task in *Declarations* in manifest? Also please check its entry point.

Comment: Yeah its in the declarations :(

Comment: Can you try to add `await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();` just before `var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();`?

Comment: I have tried that also. I found a link to some of your sample. And on my machine your example background task doesn't run. SO CONFUSED. I've got a feeling it's something to do with a visual studio update....

Comment: Weird thing, is it possible that you can test it on device? Can you try to follow [this post](http://www.romasz.net/how-to-add-a-backgroundtask/) and check if the Task runs?

Comment: Yeah, its not firing still think its to do with VS. i posted my code on onedrive if you could see if it works for you?? https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=97EFE22D865F83EE%212117

Comment: Yeah, its not firing still think its to do with VS. i posted my code on onedrive if you could see if it works for you?? onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=97EFE22D865F83EE%212117

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've tried your code, there is a problem with this specific [SystemTriggerType.NetworkStateChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtriggertype.aspx) - indeed I also don't see the registered *BackgroundTask* in *Lifecycle Events* dropdown. But if I only change the *SystemTriggerType* for example to *SystemTriggerType.TimeZoneChange* then I'm able to see it.

Here is the code modified a little:

```cs
await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
if (!taskRegistered)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Registering task inside");
    var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
    builder.Name = exampleTaskName;
    builder.TaskEntryPoint = "Tasks.Upload";
    builder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.TimeZoneChange, false));
    BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
    await new MessageDialog("Task registered!").ShowAsync();
}
```

I'm not sure why with the original code the *BackgroundTask* is not visible in VS, though it is being registered - it's in *BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks* - in this case maybe try to debug with different *SystemTriggerType* and swich to desired one with release version.

I've also tested if the *BackgroundTask* with the problematic *SystemTriggerType.NetworkStateChange* works - and indeed - it **is working**. I've modified your *BackgroundTask* a little to send a toast message when *NetworkState* changes. After registering the task, when I turn the WiFi on/off, I get a toast messgae. The code for the task:

```cs
public sealed class Upload : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Hello Pat");
        ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;
        XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);
        XmlNodeList textElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        textElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Upload Task - Yeah"));
        textElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("I'm message from your Upload task!"));
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(new ToastNotification(toastXml));
    }
}
```

The complete example you [can download here](http://1drv.ms/1qCPLMY).

Comment: @Alex702 Does it mean that it also works in your case?

Comment: Do you have any idea how you fixed it??

Comment: @Alex702 As I think it was working, but you simply can't debug it wtih VS (this particular *SystemTriggerType*) - don't ask - I don't know why. There aren't many changes in the code. Also please don't forget to mark the answer as a solution (green tick besides).

Comment: Need 15 reputation :( sorry