# Background task in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, background-task

I have Windows Phone 8 project in which I would like to have a background tasks responding to the NetworkStateChange system Trigger.

I've found this so QUESTION : [Windows Phone 8.1 Background Task - Can't Debug and won't fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388467/windows-phone-8-1-background-task-cant-debug-and-wont-fire), downloaded and re-implemented the solution (http://1drv.ms/1qCPLMY), and with a little help, that worked out fine.

I've made this simple task :
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;

```
namespace FlexCheck.Tasks
{

    public sealed class BackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = null;

        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
            _deferral.Complete();
        }

    }
}
```

In order for this to compile I need target to be Windows Phone 8.1. But then I can not reference from my Windows 8 project.

Question : Can I somehow get around this? Or is there an equivalent IBackgroundTask which can be used on Windows phone 8?

Comment: Is there a reason you target WP8 and not WP8.1? AFAIK all devices with WP8 can upgrade to 8.1.

Comment: The reason is very simple: We haven't had time yet to lift it to 8.1. And since it is a large application it is not some thins done in 5 minuts :D

Comment: I **think** you can not get around this. Windows Phone 8 has [Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202941(v=vs.105).aspx) which seem much less useful than Background Tasks.

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminDiele I'll have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background agents in Windows Phone 8 can't react to the events. It only a pieces of code that run on a timer, nothing more. Switching to WP 8.1 is the only one solution. You can try an [Audio Background agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394039(v=vs.105).aspx) as a hack and do some checks of the network state manually in the code, but this is a rule breaker and usually it won't pass the store certification.