# How to run C# code from WinPhone 8.1 Universal app when device connect to internet

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

Can i run any code from WP8.1 universal app in background when device connect to internet?
For example user work with app, but have no internet connection. App save data into local storage, user close app, then user come home and phone automatically connect to WiFi, can I run my code in bacground in this moment and for example upload data to ftp server

Comment: if it runs as a background process yes, but that would also eat up device battery while it runs in the background, so you need to optimize for that

Comment: But how can I know that Internet connection turn on?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with [SystemTrigger.NetworkStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemtriggertype.aspx). Though, you must remember that there are some limits for using network in *BackgroundTask* - more about [constraints you will find at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx).

For some help you may also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409136/2681948), you will also find a [sample code there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409136/2681948).

As for adding a *BackgroundTask*, take a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx), [this blog post](http://www.romasz.net/how-to-add-a-backgroundtask/) or [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24076237/2681948).

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh977057(v=win.10).aspx) might give you some hints on how do add some conditions to the `BackgroundTask`. On the same page, you will find additional links on the bottom for using `BackgroundTask`s.